# If $f$ measurable and $B$ a Borel set, then $f^{-1}(B)$ measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification, lebesgue-measure

> Let $f$ be a Lebesgue measurable function and $B$ be a Borel set. Show that $f^{-1}(B)$ is also measurable.

Attempt at the proof:

Suppose $f$ is Lebesgue measurable. Then $f^{-1}((\alpha,\infty))$ is measurable as well (by definition of a measurable function), $\forall\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$. We note that $(\alpha,\infty)\in\mathcal{B}$, where $\mathcal{B}$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, since:

- $\emptyset\in (\alpha,\infty)$
- $(\alpha,\infty)^c=\mathbb{R}\setminus(\alpha,\infty)\in\mathcal{B}$
- the infinite union of open sets is once again an open set

So, $(\alpha,\infty)$ is a Borel set. So let $B=(\alpha,\infty)$. Since $f$ is measurable, $f^{-1}((\alpha,\infty))$ is measurable and so $f^{-1}(B)$ is measurable.

However I'm doubtful that this is correct, since I didn't choose an arbitrary Borel set $B$. Can anyone nudge me in the right direction? Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$f$ is measurable if and only if for each Borel set A, $f^{-1}(A)$ is measurable.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/216714/f-is-measurable-if-and-only-if-for-each-borel-set-a-f-1a-is-measurable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\{A| f^{-1}(A) \text{is Borel}\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra containing all open intervals.  What can you say now?

Comment: I think that means that $\{A\mid f^{-1}(A)\text{ is Borel }\}$ is in fact a Borel $\sigma$-algebra, which is relevant because $\mathcal{B}\subset \mathcal{M}$, so this means that $f^{-1}(A)$ is Borel and hence measurable?

Comment: Isn't $f^{-1}(A)$ on the right side supposed to be Lebesgue mesurable instead of Borel?