# The inverse of a Borel set

Tags: measure-theory, measurable-functions

Let $f$ be a continuous function and $B$ a Borel set, show that $f^{-1}(B)$ is a Borel set. (Hint, the collection $\mathcal{M}=\{E: f^{^{-1}}(E)\ \  $is Borel$ \}$ is $\sigma$- algebra).

Solution: I am struggling with showing that $\mathcal{M}$ is $\sigma$ algebra. Clearly, $\emptyset \in \mathcal{M}$ since by the continuity of $f$, we have $f^{-1}(\emptyset)=\emptyset$ is open and $\emptyset$ is Borel. Is $\mathbb{R}\in \mathcal{M}$ and how to prove it is closed under the union?

Thanks for any hint.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$f$ is measurable if and only if for each Borel set A, $f^{-1}(A)$ is measurable.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/216714/f-is-measurable-if-and-only-if-for-each-borel-set-a-f-1a-is-measurable)

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathcal{O}$ denote the set of open sets and $\mathcal{B}$ the set of Borel sets.

Since $f$ is continuous we have $\mathcal{O} \subset \mathcal{M}$. Therefore

$\mathcal{B}= \sigma (\mathcal{O})  \subset \sigma (\mathcal{M})=\mathcal{M}$.

Answer (score 1):

Use the facts that $f^{-1}(\cup_i A_i)=\cup_i f^{-1} (A_i)$ and $f^{-1}(A^{c})=(f^{-1}(A))^{c}$ to shwo that $\mathcal M$ is a sigma algebra. Since it contains open sets it must contains all Borel sets and this is what we want to prove. Note: the set theoretic identities I have stated hold always; they hold for any function and any sets.

Comment: Is $\mathbb{R} \in \mathcal{M}$

Comment: Yes, $f^{-1} (\mathbb R)=\mathbb R$

Comment: Is the complement of a Borel set Borel?

Comment: Borel sets form a  sigma algebra. So complements of Borel sets are Borel.